# what is the character code for ♥ and how to use it?

Tags: javascript, regex, emoticons

im creating a emoticon js script and i cant seem to get the character code for `♥` to work ive tried `&hearts;` as the character code but dosen't work any help would be help ful

my script

```
jQuery.fn.emotion_func = function(icon_folder) {
var emotion_locate =  "emotions";
var key_stroke = { ....
         "heart": Array("&hearts;")//it dosent work 
                   ....
             };

function emotion_func(html){
for(var emotion in key_stroke){
    for(var i = 0; i < key_stroke[emotion].length; i++){
        var key = new RegExp(key_stroke[emotion][i],"g");//replace all occurenced
        html = html.replace(key,"<span style=\"background-image:url("+emotion_locate+"/"+emotion+".png); \" title="+emotion+" /></span>");
                }
            }
            return html;
        }
        return this.each(function(){
            $(this).html(emotion_func($(this).html()));
        });
    };
```

Any Help would be appreciated

Also note that im using html 5

Sorry but only @hwnd's answer worked for me

Comment: Unicode for that character is `\u2665`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The term you're looking for is "entity."  There are only a few named entities in HTML, but you can specify any character by its unicode ID:

`&#x2665;` will show up as: ♥

Answer (score 3):

You want to actually use the [Unicode escape sequence](http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-escapes#unicode) `\u2665` in your array for replacement.

```
var key_stroke = { 'heart': Array('\u2665') };
```

Answer (score 2):

The *black heart* character has the unicode code `2665`. In HTML unicode symbols can be output in the format *prefix* code *suffix* where *prefix* is always `&#x` and *suffix* is always `;`. The character you want to output has the code 2665, so it can be done like this:

```
<p>character - &#x2665;</p>
```

The output is:

```
character - ♥
```

Because you are adding the character to a JavaScript array object (as literal), you need to use the [unicode character representation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_variables,_and_literals#Unicode) (as @hwnd suggested) in JavaScript, by preceding the unicode character by `\u` (followed by the character code):

```
var a = Array('\u2665');
$('#panel').text(a[0]);
```

A reference to the unicode table containing all character codes: [unicode character table](http://unicode-table.com/en/search/?q=black+heart).

Answer (score 2):

try

```
&hearts;
```

[**FIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/zxBK2/)

HTML character codes

http://text-symbols.com/html/entities-and-descriptions/

OR

```
&#x2665;
```

[**DEMO FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/tC9mL/)

**NOTE**:dont forget to specify

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
```

and `meta` tag too

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type">
```

Comment: welcome to the club, I got targeted by a mysterious downvote, too :-P

Answer (score 1):

Another HTML code for the heart sign: ♥

```
&#9829;
```

see it working in this [JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Hw7LV/)

Answer (score 1):

### Red Heart Symbol Hex Code

If you want to use red heart variant you have to use two unicodes:
U+2764 - stands for [heavy black heart](https://www.htmlsymbols.xyz/unicode/U+2764)
U+FE0F - is a [variation selector](https://codepoints.net/U+FE0F)

To insert ❤️ symbol in html type it's hexcode
`<p>&#x2764;&#xFE0F;</p>`

Answer (score 0):

You can see different **Special and Math Symbols in HTML and JavaScript** [here](http://www.javascripter.net/faq/mathsymbols.htm).